# how do i refer to the $index of the parent loop inside a nested ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs, pug, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am nesting ng-repeat in my App.

In that I'm trying to refer to the  $index of parent loop

```
.div(ng-repeat= item in items)
  p(ng-repeat= detail in item.details)
    a(href='#') // $$ index ?
```

how do i refer to the $index of the parent loop (ie. $index of item) inside a nested ng-repeat?

(the above code is in jade)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use scope' parent' `$index`: `$parent.$index`. Something like (just guess , i don't know much about Jade):

```
.div(ng-repeat= item in items)
  p(ng-repeat= detail in item.details)
    a(ng-href='#/{{$parent.$index}}')
```

Working example (not Jade): http://jsfiddle.net/Ysxsx/